# Format USB drive to NTFS/FAT from UDF

Tags: usb, partitioning, ntfs, formatting, udf

I formatted a USB drive UDF to boot an ISO image and now I can't find a way to get it back to being in NTFS/FAT or another usable format.

Do I need a 3rd party tool?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the HP Drive Key utility would do this.

Roadkil's Boot Builder's may do this.

Roadkil's Disk Wipe will wipe it completely. When you unplug/plug it in again windows will say the drive hasn't been formatted and prompt you to. If not, you should see it in Disk Management. Just be careful that you wipe the correct drive!

Answer (score 0):

[GParted LiveCD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) is always a good option for all things related to partitions.

[image: gparted livecd]